# Git checkout multiple commits

Tags: git

I am using EAGLE CAD with git for revision control.  EAGLE stores its files as xml.  I have different board revisions and I tag them with annotated tags so I can check out the revision whenever I want to view it.

Most users will find that a diff will be sufficient to compare two commits, but it would be much more illuminating for me to be able to open two files with EAGLE to visually compare them.

I am aware that there is some software out there [for this specific application](https://github.com/jotux/eagle-diff), but I just want to know how to checkout two commits of the same file into the working directory.

Comment: `git show commit:path/to/file >oldcopy_of_file`

Comment: @jthill, please turn it into an answer as it's the only sensible thing to do (other than the contrib `new-worktree` script which is too heavy-weight for this simple task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One file:

```
git show $commit:path/to/file.xml > mycopy.xml
```

All the files, clone is built for this, it's dirt cheap:

```
git tag oldcommit $commit
git clone --branch oldcommit ../oldcommit
git tag -d oldcommit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a primitive approach.

```
git checkout otherCommit file.xml
cp file.xml file.1.xml
git checkout anotherCommit file.xml
cp file.xml file.2.xml
```